# regarding building regression models including interaction effects in lm

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I have a data set read as follows

```
test<-read.csv("data.csv",sep=",",header=T)
```

There are 10 predictor variables. The first column is response variables

```
x<-test[,-c(1)]
y<-test[,1]
```

If I would like to test a model with the first three predictor variables including their interaction terms, here is what I did with `lm`

```
test.model<-lm(y~x[,1]*x[,2]*x[,3], data=test)
```

But it turns out that the the resulting model also includes the interaction term of `x[, 1]:x[, 2]:x[, 3]` How can I limit the model with just two factor interactions, such as `x[, 1]:x[, 2]`, `x[, 2]:x[, 3]` and `x[, 1]:x[, 3]`

If I would like to consider all 10 predictor variables, instead of writing `x[,1]*x[,2]*x[,3]*x[,4]*...x[,10]`, are there convienent ways to write this formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the highest order of interactions with `^`.

```
y ~ (x[,1] + x[,2] + x[,3]) ^ 2
```

results in all two-variable interactions and main effects.

Answer (score 0):

Two points. It makes no sense to extract the predictor and response as separate items if you are also going to supply a data argument. At worst it will start to fail at strange moments, but at a minimum it will confuse your collaborators. It's going to be much easy to interpret if you have meaningful column names.

As Sven points out you can use the "^" formula operator which means something quite different than exponentiation. I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate SO question so will now do a bit of searching.